# データプロット上を通る平滑化・近似

Tags: python

pythonで 以下のデータをすべてのデータプロット上を通る線で平滑化（近似）？したいのですが何かいい方法ご存じではないですか？webでも自分なりに調べてみましたがこれといった方法が見つかりませんでした．

x軸 y軸
0   92
6   105
11  114
20  125
30  148
40  141

Answer (score 1):

スプライン補間するのはいかがでしょうか

【コード例】

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def spline1(x,y,point):
    f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y,kind="cubic") 
    X = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],num=point,endpoint=True)
    Y = f(X)
    return X,Y

x = [0, 6, 11, 20, 30, 40]
y = [92, 105, 114, 125, 148, 141]
a1,b1 = spline1(x,y,1000)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro',label="point")
plt.plot(a1,b1,label="interp1d")
plt.title("spline")
plt.xlim([-5, 45])
plt.ylim([80, 160])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.grid(which='major',color='black',linestyle='-')
plt.grid(which='minor',color='black',linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

【実行結果】
[image: 実行結果]

以下のページを参考にしました。ほとんど丸写しです。
[pythonでxy座標上の離散点をスプライン補間](https://qiita.com/Ken227/items/aee6c82ec6bab92e6abf)